# Why HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() fails after connecting to a VPN?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to control a computer in another room over a local LAN and not the internet which is an important distinction in this case.  This is done by sending `HttpWebRequests` with query strings that command the remote computer to do certain things. One of commands is to tell the remote computer to connect to a VPN using Cisco's AnyConnect client.  When it connects, it should send back a reply to the controlling computer that it successfully connected.

For some reason, the reply which is a `HttpWebRequest` will time out.  The strange thing is that I can send `HttpWebRequests` over the internet with no problem, so it seems to be only a local LAN issue.  To get around this issue, I have created a separate console app that is called just to send the replys.  I am not sure what is different about it, but it works.

Here is the code from the console app and those are two same lines used in the main program that fail to work.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // args[0] contains query string ie ?reply=VPNSuccess
        HttpWebRequest httpWebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new  Uri("http://192.168.1.11:1000" + args[0]));
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebReq.GetResponse();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the vpn is connected the remote machine likely has a new IP address on a different subnet that cannot route back to you.

If I connect a vpn to my company HQ from my house, once the vpn connects I can no longer ping machines on my local network by default. This can be changed via various settings.

Comment: Can you explain why the separate console app is able to send the reply?

Comment: Nope. This is just a theory based on my experience with VPN connections. It's a simple test... connect the vpn and see if you can ping back and forth, or try to telnet to the port in question.

Comment: Yes, I can ping back and forth no problem.